# C++ how can I pass reference from one function to another?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters, reference

I have the next function:

```
void UserInterface::showMenu(vector<GraphicsCard> *allCards) {
    int currentCard = 0;
    string userInput = "";

    cout << "1: Show Previous, 2: Show Next" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

    switch (stoi(userInput)) {
        case 1:
            if (currentCard > 0) {
                currentCard--;
            }
            UserInterface::showGraphicsCardTable(&allCards[currentCard]);
            UserInterface::showMenu(allCards);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (currentCard < allCards->size()) {
                currentCard++;
            }
            UserInterface::showGraphicsCardTable(&allCards[currentCard]);
            UserInterface::showMenu(allCards);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass a reference to the particular element of the vector to the `void UserInterface::showGraphicsCardTable(GraphicsCard *card)` function. And the problem is `&allCards[currentCard]` doesn't work in this case.
How can I pass the reference further?

Comment: You're asking about passing references while in fact you are passing pointers around. Just change your functions to take vector<GraphicsCard>& and GraphicsCard&. Also moving the 2 duplicated lines out of the switch wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @stijn Thank you! I think I need to learn the difference between them. P.S. and you're right about duplicate lines. However, there will much more options in the menu. :)

Comment: @stijn And I'm sorry, I've just understood what you mean about duplicated lines and I'll surely do that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
UserInterface::showGraphicsCardTable(&allCards[currentCard]);
```

to this:

```
UserInterface::showGraphicsCardTable(&((*allCards)[currentCard]));
```

By the way, why to pass a pointer in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)? Pass a reference in `showMenu()` instead! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your awesome advice! :)

Comment: @W.F. My bad, I thought I pressed the button. :)